# dataflow - advanced profiles

Tags: import, dataflow

I have a problem with advanced import profiles. I get a blank page when opening dataflow - advanced profiles. I opened exception.log and got the following lines:

```
> 2015-02-04T18:42:43+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Ongeldig bloktype: CommerceExtensions_Productimportexport_Block_Adminhtml_System_Convert_Profile_Grid' in /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(38142): Mage::throwException('Ongeldig blokty...')
#1 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(38084): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('adminhtml/syste...', Array)
#2 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container.php(66): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/syste...', 'system_convert_...')
#3 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(1223): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->_prepareLayout()
#4 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(38103): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#5 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Convert/ProfileController.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/syste...', 'convert_profile')
#6 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(24141): Mage_Adminhtml_System_Convert_ProfileController->indexAction()
#7 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(28525): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#8 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(28059): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(30831): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/index.php(87): Mage::run('dutch', 'store')
#12 {main}
2015-02-04T18:56:46+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Ongeldig bloktype: CommerceExtensions_Productimportexport_Block_Adminhtml_System_Convert_Profile_Grid' in /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(38142): Mage::throwException('Ongeldig blokty...')
#1 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(38084): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('adminhtml/syste...', Array)
#2 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container.php(66): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/syste...', 'system_convert_...')
#3 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(1223): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->_prepareLayout()
#4 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(38103): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#5 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Convert/ProfileController.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/syste...', 'convert_profile')
#6 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(24141): Mage_Adminhtml_System_Convert_ProfileController->indexAction()
#7 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(28525): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#8 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(28059): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(30831): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/index.php(87): Mage::run('dutch', 'store')
#12 {main}
2015-02-09T12:00:41+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Ongeldig bloktype: CommerceExtensions_Productimportexport_Block_Adminhtml_System_Convert_Profile_Grid' in /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(38142): Mage::throwException('Ongeldig blokty...')
#1 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(38084): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('adminhtml/syste...', Array)
#2 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container.php(66): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/syste...', 'system_convert_...')
#3 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(1223): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->_prepareLayout()
#4 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(38103): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#5 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Convert/ProfileController.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/syste...', 'convert_profile')
#6 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(24141): Mage_Adminhtml_System_Convert_ProfileController->indexAction()
#7 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(28525): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#8 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(28059): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/includes/src/__default.php(30831): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /storage/web/public/sites/www.bjornvenema.nl/index.php(87): Mage::run('dutch', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

What is the possible problem?

Thanks in advance.

Bjorn Venema

Comment: Check in with the developer of CommerceExtensions. He is very helpful from my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Bjorn Venema,you need recompile the code from admin. Please goto admin>System>:

Navigate to `System > Tools > Compilation page and click on Disable button`

Navigate to System > Cache Management screen and use Flush Cache button

Again enable Compilation.

see at 
http://support.createhosting.co.nz/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=49

Comment: Nothing you said did work. :(

Comment: is CommerceExtensions_Productimportexport_Block_Adminhtml_System_Convert_Profile_Grid class is exit on your system?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: please check Gr‌​id.php exits in CommerceExtensions>Productimportexport>Block_Adminhtml>System>Convert>Profile

Comment: This is the code:

<?php

class CommerceExtensions_Productimportexport_Block_Adminhtml_System_Convert_Gui_Grid
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Convert_Gui_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('dataflow/profile_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_type', array('notnull'=>''))
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_commerce_extensions', 0);

        $this->setCollection($collection);
    }
}